# How to solve this calc. of variations problem with inequality constraint?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I have the following calculus of variations problem:

$$\min_{f(\cdot)}\int_0^1(f(x)+g(x))^\phi dx \quad \text { s.t. } \int_0^1f(x)dx=A, \quad f(x)\geq 0 \quad \forall x\in [0,1]$$

For some given function $g(x)\geq0$ and a given constant $A>0$. $g(x)$ satisfies the following conditions:

- $g(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,a]$ for some $a\in[0,1]$.
- $g'(x) >0$ on $(a,1)$
- Hence $g(x)\geq 0$

I try to apply the Kuhn Tucker theorem and formulate the lagrangian:

$$\int_0^1\left[(f(x)+g(x))^\phi -\lambda (f(x)-A)-\mu_x (f(x)-0)\right ]dx$$

> The optimization conditions are:
>
> $$\begin{align}&\phi(f(x)+g(x))^{\phi-1}-\lambda=\mu_x\\
> &\mu_xf(x)=0\\
> &\mu_x\geq 0, f(x)\geq 0\\
> &\int_0^1f(x)dx=A
> \end{align}$$

**I honestly, don't really know where to start solving a problem with inequality constraint like this. I can draw the picture of what I think it should be, but I'm not sure how to do it analytically (without hand waving to the picture).**

Comment: Is there any restriction on the value of $\phi$?

Comment: Whoops, yes $\phi$ is nonpositive. I didnt think that would matter though.

Comment: Let's say its also nonzero. So its negative.

Comment: It matters. If $\phi>1$, then the problem does not have a solution.

Comment: If you let $f(x)=A/\epsilon$ for $x\in[1-\epsilon,1]$ and $0$ otherwise, for small $\epsilon$, you can make the integral be close to $\int_0^1g^\phi$ as you like.  Which might be infinite if $a>0$.